# Can read from google sheet, but can't update it

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets-api

I am using google sheets api 4 and I can read from sheets, but when I try updating I get an error

`You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit. [400]`

I am creating service like this:

```
return new SheetsService(
       new BaseClientService.Initializer()
       {
          HttpClientInitializer = GoogleCredential
          .FromStream(stream)
          .CreateScoped(scopes)
          .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential
       });
```

And scopes are:

```
private readonly string[] scopes =
    {
        SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets,
        SheetsService.Scope.DriveReadonly
    };
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Based on the error message, looks like you are trying to edit a protected cell. Check [google documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: @Cleptus You are right, I was only reading google `google sheets api` doc, thank you. Feel free to post this as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cleptus said, cell in my sheet was protected, it wasn't related to API, to resolve this issue check [link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)